# Indentify Duplicate From a Document Library using a specific field (and with administration limits)

Tags: document-library, duplicate

I would like help on a problem i have creating a documents library for my project team.
I'm an HR consultant and have to manage a lot of resumes. The problem is that the same resumes can be sent by different subcontracting companies, and I have to know the name of that resumes.

So, I would like to identify (with an alert) duplicates when I upload a document or in a documents library column,  based on columns "Name&Surname". In fact the documents name will not the same (but on the same format Name_Surname_Company_Position).

The trick there is that the sharepoint is not mine, and full of my company subsites, I can't access Sharepoint Designer and just have that documents library under my administration.

Is anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

In the terms of document libraries, if you have 2 resumes from the same person named differently, then those are different files and the only way to know they are different is to view them and delete one.

Now if you create additional columns of data to track other information, one could be one where you specify your "Primary Key".  Then in your views, you can create a view where this field is the group by field.  If you see a 2 next to anyone, you know it's a duplicate and one can be deleted.

This is all manual because each resume has to be reviewed and tagged appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for your help,
I have a column wich display "Name&Surname" which basically is equal to a Primary Key.
But is there any solution to check duplicate from that "automatically ?" I mean, my database contain more than 3000 resumes, I can't check manually ....

Comment: If you group by that field in a view, it will show you how many items there are based on that surname combination.  You could try using a workflow to do it automatically, but they can be a little problematic querying the list looking for duplicates. I have used this in the past with mixed results, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointworkflow/thread/9605f65b-7026-47fb-af05-c555f6de222f.

Comment: It seems it can help me, but i'm not familiar with workflow, it may be a "newbie" question but, does the workflow impact all the sharepoint site (my document library as well as the others?), there is a lot of different libraries in the sites and i don't want to broke something on those ... For the solution itself as i understood the solution It will mail the creator but, is it possible to change that to idk ... a column with "duplicate detected" writed? Thx for help anywat PirateEric!

Comment: The workflow will only affect the document library in this case.  Yes, if you had a column, instead of emailing someone, you can use the update item action to set a field value.